# Drupal session create help needed

Tags: drupal

I want to create our own session in Drupal root index.php.

Please suggest me how to create session in Drupal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the session variable using the `$_SESSION superglobal` variable.Use `session_start`() to start a session.Use `unset()` to unset the session variable

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['index'] = "myValue"; //Assign your value to the session variable
```

You can obtain the value of the `session` variable using the following code

```
session_start();
echo $_SESSION['index']; //Prints the session variable.
```